# How do you say the title that some teacher has?

Tags: word-usage

For example, if he graduates in Physical Education and he teach it, can I put: Licensed (teaching) in Physical Education or graduate in Physical Education. 
Or, what do you recommend me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The two are not the same. Being a graduate in a subject is not always a licence to teach it.

Usually the type, classification and subject of a degree would be given separately from any professional entitlement; for example:

BSc(Hons) 2.1 Physical Education, University of Blank, 2018

Qualified Teacher Status, Physical Education, Registration 23456, 2019

This would be fairly typical for the UK. Other countries' practice will vary widely.

Answer (score 1):

Terms related to qualifications in teaching vary heavily between countries. If you want to refer to such qualifications in a non-English-speaking country, I would say you should attempt to translate the local term.

However, if you just want to say what their university degree was in, it's just "graduate in X", and I'm fairly sure that's consistent between English-speaking countries. You could also say they "have a degree in X", or "hold a degree in X". In most contexts, just saying "degree" refers to a bachelor's degree.

Comment: I got it, but for example here in Colombia there is a career called lisenced in Pysical education, it means that the person will be able to teach it, without another degree.So in that case, how can I translate to English?

Comment: So, the local Spanish term doesn't include *teacher*, just *physical education*? Does it exist for other subjects, or just for physical education? If it's just for PE, I'd say "licensed physical educator", as the license in ... education could be taken to mean the license applies only to education. It seems a little weird, though, because "physical educator" isn't a thing. You could equally use "licensed teacher of physical education", which would work for subjects other than PE as well, even without "education" in the title. Some might prefer "licensed instructor in" rather than "teacher of".

Comment: I think OP wants to say Licentiate in Physical Education. In Spanish, there is one word both for "licentiate" and "licensed": "licenciado" (a noun when it means "licentiate", and an adjective when it means "licensed").